# How to convert switch case to lookup table

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to convert this switch case to possibly a lookup table using keys, values, etc.

Here is the switch case

```
getContactTypeTitle(contactTypeCode: string): string {
    let contactType = 'Site Contact';
    switch (contactTypeCode) {
        case 'SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleDirector':
            contactType = 'Principle Director';
            break;

        case 'SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleAsstDir':
            contactType = 'Principle Assistant Director';
            break;

        case 'SiteApp_CACFP_Cook':
            contactType = 'Cook';
            break;
    }

    return contactType;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A Map lookup would be pretty simple to implement.

```
const contactTypeByCode = new Map([
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleDirector', 'Principle Director'],
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleAsstDir', 'Principle Assistant Director'],
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_Cook', 'Cook'],
]);
const getContactTypeTitle = (contactTypeCode: string) {
    return contactTypeByCode.get(contactTypeCode) || 'Site Contact';
};
```

You might wish to increase the type-safety by requiring the caller to pass a code that's in the Map already.

```
const contactTypeByCodeArr = [
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleDirector', 'Principle Director'],
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_PrincipleAsstDir', 'Principle Assistant Director'],
    ['SiteApp_CACFP_Cook', 'Cook'],
] as const;
type ContactCode = typeof contactTypeByCodeArr[number][0];
const contactTypeByCode = new Map(contactTypeByCodeArr);
const getContactTypeTitle = (contactTypeCode: ContactCode) {
    return contactTypeByCode.get(contactTypeCode);
};
```